# Calculation of time complexity of a function that finds all possible sum combinations of a given number from the list

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm a bit confused on how to start the calculation of time complexity for the given function,

```
function func(A, x):
         A.sort()
         result = []
         Mystery(A, x, 0, [], result)
         return result`
function Mystery(A, x, start, p, result):
          if x == 0:
             result.append(p)
             return
          if x < 0:
             return
         for i from start to n - 1:
             Mystery(A, x - A[i], i + 1, p + [A[i]], result)
```

where it gives the result as a list of lists that when each list added up equals to the number x, here A is a list with length n

I calculated a bit and came up with T(n,x) = O(1) + T(n-1, x-A[0]) + T(n-2, x-A[1]) ... T(n-i, x-A[n-1]) although this is what confuses me, as I don't know if this is the correct way to proceed or I made a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case  is larger than the sum of all array elements. In that case the program tries all subsequences of the input array. In other words, all combinations are made in  where there are two possibilities for each array element in : either it is in  or it is not. This gives us 2 possibilities for . All of them are created in the worst case. The average size of  is O() which is also the time complexity to create one such version of  (which happens in the expression `p + [A[i]]` at each recursive call).

And so the time complexity is O(2)